# Using Laravel and Ionic together with Nginx routes

Tags: laravel, nginx, ionic-framework, ionic3, laravel-5.7

I have an Ionic 3 web app where I'm using Laravel for both the API and the back-end manager with Nova. Ideally, I'd like my setup to be:

Server 1: example.com serving only my static Ionic App

Server 2: api.example.com serving my Laravel API

Server 2: example.com/admin serving my Laravel backend with Nova

This is easy with Laravel forge, except that I want api.example.com and example.com/admin to be powered by the same application. Right now it looks like I would need my code to live as two separate applications, one for api. and one for /admin.

It makes sense that there would be a way to configure Nginx to point both to the same place, but how, and which one, and where?

Comment: i implement the same thing like you for admin layer i use voyager and api with CORS Middleware and JWTAuth and all worked good but ionic app had problem to call apis because ssl https rest calls error there and i dont know is the nginix configuration or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a redirect from /admin to the appropriate destination. You can either do this in nginx or in Ionic.